How to override the internal read query of class or method in django
I wan't to override the internal read query present inside my class or method. I wan't to write generalised solution so that it should work on the class or method where I wan't to modify the read queries.
I am trying to do using decorators, middleware and metaclasses but I am unable to access the internal read query of function.
I just wan't to modify it to take it from read replica. but I can't do this to all read query. I can only modify read query to take it from read replica for few class or method.
master_models.CarTransmission.objects.filter(  # pylint: disable=E1101 variant_id__in=self.variant_ids ).values_list(*self.specifications, named=True)
modify this to-
  master_models.CarTransmission.objects.using('replica').filter(  # pylint: disable=E1101 variant_id__in=self.variant_ids ).values_list(*self.specifications, named=True)
original-
 model = get_object_or_404(master_models.Model,slug=slug)
modify this to -
model = get_object_or_404(master_models.Model.objects.using('replica'),slug=slug)
The logic that I am expecting should be specific to class and method. If I apply that on class all the method present should modify all the internal read query. Is it possible or I should go to all query and write .using('replica')?
Pleaser don't provide solution which work for some specific app like using routing to move it to redirect to replica as they will be going to work on whole project or on some app not specific to method or class.

You can use a database router [Django-doc] for this:
# app_name/router.py


class ReplicateRouter:
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        return 'replicate'
for queries that thus read from the database, it will use the replicate database instead.
and install the router in the settings:
# settings.py

DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['app_name.router.ReplicateRouter']
You can also add more control to this, for example only for certain models with:
# app_name/router.py


class ReplicateRouter:
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if hasattr(model, 'use_replicate_for_read', False):
            return 'replicate'
and then attach a user_replicate_for_read attribute on the model for which you want to do this:
# app_name/models.py


class CarTransmission(models.Model):
    use_replicate_for_read = True
    # …

This I have already done but the point where I stuck is
I am not able to access attribute present in view class use_replicate_for_read.
we are not able to access django view class attribute inside db router file.
do you know any way to access use_replicate_for_read inside db router.py file

I wan't control over django view class. The class which I wan't to redirect to read replica should only go to read replica.

@AyushKumar: well that makes not much sense, since there is not always a view involved anyway: you can use management commands for example to make ORM queries, and the entire idea of a MVC is exactly that the model is unaware of the view.

@AyushKumar: strictly speaking you could define an object to work with a global-state like pattern, but that seems so be a horrible idea from an architectural point of view.

My requirement is simple. I have to change in few api so that they redirect to read replica. that can be achieved If I am able to understand the request is coming from those api or not.
I can't directly redirect to all read query to read replica. This may cause problem if some api have both read and write and also the data of few api should be updated immediately for user.
can you let me some way to approach this.
please elaborate a bit to understand easily.

please suggest If you have any idea to solve this. and elaborate little bit. so it is easy to understand.
